I am rolling a die until I get a $3,4,5$, or $6$. Will the odds of ending on an odd number of casts be same as the odds of stopping on an even number?
I think that the odds are the same. My friend thinks they are different.
She thinks that if the odds of stopping on an even number of casts is $A$; then the odds of stopping on an odd number of casts is $1-A$.
She is about to take a probability test; a rapid response is appreciated.

Can you rapidly tell us on what basis you and your friend came to the differing conclusions ?

Since the probability that it ends on the first cast is $\frac 23$, it's obviously impossible that the two probabilities could be the same.

As Jon has observed, the probability is $3/4$ in this case.
In general, you can ask: I flip a coin that comes up heads with probability $p$ until I get heads.  What is the probability that this takes an odd number of flips?  It turns out that this is always greater than $1/2$.
One way to see this - there's a greater chance that it takes one flip than two, three flips than four, and so on, because the probability that the first head is on the $n$th flip is $q^{n-1} p$ and this decreases as $n$ increases.  Here $q = 1-p$, as is standard in this sort of problem.
Alternately, you can work out the explicit probability of getting an odd number of heads as
$$p + q^2 p + q^4 p + \cdots = {p \over 1-q^2} = {p \over 1-(1-p)^2} = {p \over 2p-p^2} = {1 \over 2-p} $$
and since $p > 0$ we have $1/(2-p) > 1/2$.

The probability of ending on an odd number of casts is $$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4 \; + \;  ... \; = \frac{3}{4}$$ So the probabilities are unequal.
